# JPQL Query to get specific element from nested one to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to describe a system using jpa. System setup is asfollows:
Entities are: apartment, room and reservation.
Apartment can have multiple rooms, and rooms can have multiple reservations.

Relevant code is bellow:

Apartment entity

```
@Entity
public class Apartman {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idapartman")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int idapartman;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "apartman", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Soba> rooms;
    ...
```

Room entity

```
@Entity
public class Soba implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idroom")
    private int idroom;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idapartman", nullable=false)
    private Apartman apartman;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Reservation> reservations= new ArrayList<Reservation>();
```

Reservation entity

```
@Entity
public class Reservationimplements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idrservation")
    private int idrservation;

    @Column(name="dateIn")
    @Temporal(DATE)
    private Date dateIn;

    @Column(name="dateOut")
    @Temporal(DATE)
    private Date dateOut;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idroom", nullable=false)
    private Room room;
```

What I would want to do is get all rooms inside an apartment of given name that don't have reservations that overlap with given date range.
Every reservation has check-in date and check-out date. 
User enters apartment name, in date and out date.

I want to do:
Filter rooms that belong to the apartment with the given name
For every room check all of its reservations, and leave only rooms where there are no overlaps in any of reservations with in and out date.

Currently I only fetch rooms from Apartment, like this

```
return em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Apartman a JOIN a.sobe s WHERE a.name= :name).setParameter("name", name).getResultList();
```

I have to add reservations in the calculation. How do I do that?

Comment: so "JOIN s.reservations r".

Comment: I wrote query like this
`SELECT s FROM Apartman a JOIN a.sobe s WHERE a.naziv = :naziv JOIN s.reservations r WHERE ((:in <= r.dateIn) and (:out >= r.dateOut))`
but I get this error `The expression is not a valid conditional expression.` and `The query contains a malformed ending.`

Comment: Why have you put a JOIN in the WHERE clause?! All JOINs go in the FROM clause. Also you have 2 WHERE's in that

Comment: You're right, I was to quick on the keyboard. This seems to work:
`SELECT s FROM Apartman a JOIN a.room rs JOIN s.reservations re WHERE a.name= :name AND NOT ((:in<= re.dateOut) AND (:out>= re.dateIn))`
But this seems to take into consideration only the rooms that have reservations. How do I take into consideration rooms that don't have reservations (they should be included in the select)

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of JOIN perhaps ...

Comment: Thanks for this I'll try it out.
@NeilStockton Sorry for bothering you, but I'm rusty with sql. From current query, how could I select distinct rooms based on their id? Can I select distinct entities by explicitly naming the disctinction criteria?